# Reference for zero sum problems?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-group-theory

I am looking for books/ references which deal with the analysis of [zero sum problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem) and weighted zero sum problems. I have found some articles on the internet, but they seem insufficient.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Please respond to answers,don't overlook them. If not helpful , atleast mention that if you want to get better response in future.